# PHP Framework and ORM vs Stored Procedures

Tags: php, zend-framework, cakephp, orm, symfony1

I am in the process of picking a PHP framework for a web application I am starting. I have never really used a framework in the past but with this project there is a great need.

I have been debating between the usual suspects; CakePHP, Zend Framework and Symfony. I have been going back and forth about which framework will work best for me and this project. I am leaning towards CakePHP but I am still researching.

My question is not what framework is best. I know there is no real answer to that and there are tons of posts related to this subject. My question is related to the Model and ORM. I have read a lot about ORMs being slow and I am concerned about speed. I am very comfortable writing SQL and in the past have tried to keep all of my database interactions in stored procedures.

I am looking for some feedback about using CakePHP's ORM or Doctrine with Zend or Symfony as apposed to keeping everything in stored procedures. I know stored procedures are going to be faster but what else will I loose if I do not use an ORM? I understand that an ORM will give me database abstraction but in my mind that just helps people who do not write SQL. I also know that I do not know enough about ORMs.

If anyone can give me some feedback about this and which framework might be best based on using or not using an ORM.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: any feedback about these passionate answers ?

Comment: Thanks everyone for the great feedback. I am going to go with Doctrine 2.

Answer (score 8):

**0) Bang for effort**

The key advantage with an ORM is that you don't spend as much time dealing with the persistence layer.  A pre-written ORM ( I have worked with EclipseLink) will provide a ton of things you probably won't get in custom written stored procs.  I think it's worth thinking about how much time you want to spend writing your persistence layer.

**1) Caching**

All the major ORMs provide multi-level distributed caches.  Combined with Named/Predefined queries you can get SQL queries that don't actually have to go to the database.  This can give you excellent performance.

**2) Abstraction**

ORMs allow you to define your table layout in one location and then they manage all the painful mapping between columns/tables and objects.  Some will allow you to remap column, table and schema names without changing any code at all.  If you work with people who like to change things around this can really simplify things.

**3) Speed**

Some ORMs can have bad performance, but it really is based on how you use it.  I find that you tend to end up over-querying for things.  On the other hand, you get things like built-in query profilers.  You can write custom SQL for queries if you find you aren't getting the performance you need.

Answer (score 3):

A framework implements mainly three kinds of features :

1. the flow between "getting a request" and "rendering a page". That's were you put things like MVC, router, etc...
2. the way to manage your model and it's persistence. That's where you see acronyms like ORM, DBAL, DAO
3. Components. Features, often working also standalone. Like Xml parsing, i18n handling, pdf generation...

When you choose your framework, it in facts means that you choose 1). It's the thing you will certainly have to stick with, it's the flow of your application. 2) and 3) ? You can integrate those you prefer. As an example, i'm on Zend Framework with most of it's components, but use Doctrine ORM 2 and Symfony's Dependency injection. A friend of mine is on Symfony 2, uses Doctrine ORM too, but does it's pdf generation and mail management with Zend's related components.

The other thing you need to know if that currently there is a "second generation" of php frameworks/orm's, (re)written to take advantage of the new php 5.3 features, and/or to solve the general performance/[coupling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_%28computer_science%29) issues they (nearly) all had. Some of them are production ready, some are still under development :

- Doctrine ORM 2 (production ready)
- Symfony 2 (production ready)
- CakePhp 2 (in RC 2 currently, but by the time your project is ready it should be stable)
- Zend Framework 2 (still under active development, but normally not for so long)
- FLOW 3 (beta2, should be ready soon too)

For the ORM part, i'll recommend using one, especially Doctrine's. @Mark and @iainp999 explained perfectly why.

Answer (score 3):

Mark Robinson gives a great response.  I'm just going to back up what he says by giving our experience with Doctrine2.

I chose to use Doctrine2 as our ORM with Zend Framework a little while back.  Our project is still being developed, but choosing D2 has been a decision we've not regretted one bit.  Whilst you still need to give a lot of thought to your data architecture, D2 gives you the flexibility to be able to modify that model at a later date if needs be.  It allowed us to try things out quickly in the early stages and the room to grow and change later when we decided that things weren't quite right - it happens.

In relation to Mark's point about abstraction.  One of the other things I love about D2 is that we're working with plain old PHP objects.  Don't underestimate the power of being able to think in terms of objects - both for the people responsible for modelling the data and the developers who work with the data - it'll make your life easier, trust me.  Also, having inline documentation of the ORM mapping (if you choose the docblock approach) is nice.

Right, performance.  As Mark says, there are ways and means to speed things up - but there's always going to be some overhead.  Whenever you introduce another software layer, there'll be some performance hit, but it's a tradeoff.  For us, the tradeoff - the advantages of using the ORM vs performance - is worth it.  We'd spend more time debugging code and not getting things done without the ORM.

Anyway, D2 can help you with caching for queries, results and metadata.  Whilst you probably just want an array cache during development, it's great that the facility for things like APC, memcache etc. is there when you go to test and deploy.  You could even develop your own if you're brave.

http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/caching.html

Hope that helps, I've probably missed stuff, but if you have any questions just fire them in and I'll do my best.

Answer (score -3):

ORMs are for programmers who don't "grock" SQL!

Yes ORMs make it easier (or at least require less lines of code) to write simple CRUD stuff, but when you get to more complex requirements its like trying to write SQL with a piece of wet spaghetti from ten feet away.

So stick with SQL.

Its worth looking at something like "SQLMap" which is ORM starting from the "R"elational side of the mapping (most try to map an "O"bject on to a table). This will allow you to write the SQL yourself and generate the appropriate "helper" classes to easily access the results in your program.

Comment: Highly opinionated post that doesn't answer the q.

Comment: Stick with SQL is a pretty specific answer!

Comment: If you start your answer with an insult: "ORMs are for programmers who don't "grock" SQL!" you can't really expect anything than downvotes. ORM has clearly other benefits than being used by people who can't write SQL.

Comment: @James, +1 -- maybe you just needed a winking smiley after your opening comment to avoid the down votes? I agree with your statements, but I do recognize that ORM has a place. It's just not an "ultimate" kind of a solution.

Comment: @Chris -- thanks! There seems to be a sense of humor failure on Stack overflow these days. I think this was a serious answer to the question phrased in a non serious manner. If the OP is skilled in SQL and happy with it then using an ORM will bring very little benefit.

Comment: Late to the game... ORM is for people who DO grok SQL and know that it's better to have someone else write your queries.

Comment: @wmid -- Writing the queries is OK, but, most ORMs write the database schema which causes so many problems I don't know where to begin.